# Java HttpURLConnection doesn't connect when I call connect()

Tags: java, url, connection, http-status-code-302, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to write a program to do automated testing on my webapp.  To accomplish this, I open up a connection using HttpURLConnection.

One of the pages that I'm trying to test performs a 302 redirect.  My test code looks like this :

```
URL currentUrl = new URL(urlToSend);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) currentUrl.openConnection();
connection.connect();
system.out.println(connection.getURL().toString());
```

So, let's say that urlToSend is http://www.foo.com/bar.jsp, and that this page redirects you to http://www.foo.com/quux.jsp.  My println statement should print out http://www.foo.com/quux.jsp, right?

WRONG.

The redirect never happens, and it prints out the original URL.  However, if I change switch out the connection.connect() line with a call to connection.getResponseCode(), it magically works.

```
URL currentUrl = new URL(urlToSend);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) currentUrl.openConnection();
//connection.connect();
connection.getResponseCode();
system.out.println(connection.getURL().toString());
```

Why am I seeing this behavior?  Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `connect()` method just creates a connection. You have to commit the request (by calling `getInputStream()`, `getResponseCode()`, or `getResponseMessage()`) for the response to be returned and processed.

Comment: Thank you for this! Been trying to understand why people are issuing getInputStream() and such without ever calling connect(). You just clarified that to me.

Answer (score 2):

The [connect()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) method is implemented in the URLConnection class, and is not overridden by the [HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class.

The URLConnection class is not aware of HTTP, and so should not follow the HTTP redirect even if it was creating a real connection.

If you want behaviour intrinsic to the HTTP protocol, you probably want to stick to methods implemented in the HttpURLConnection class, as the getResponseCode() method is.

Answer (score 0):

Try [setFollowRedirects](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean)), as it might help. Actually, try `getFollowRedirects` to see if it's the problem, first (unlikely since it's true by default).

**Edit:** If this is not your problem, I would try reading something from the connection (as you do with `getResponseCode` but I would try also `getHeaderField` to see if reading anything at all causes the redirect to be respected).

Comment: Already tried that, getFollowRedirects returns true.  Also, I'm having a separate problem with setFollowRedirects in a separate test.  Basically, setInstanceFollowRedirects() doesn't do anything, whereas setFollowRedirects() does what it's supposed to.  However, I figured it would be better to ask about that in a separate post since it's a separate problem.

Comment: @sangfroid I think you'll find that you have to actually read something from the connection to get the redirect to be read/respected.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your onCreate

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/) from apache.