# HttpURLConnection connect() won't work

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

I try to connect the php on my PC , but the Android code will stop at `con.connect()`
I have no idea what happen it is.

```
 public String doInBackground(Void... arg0){
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    String urlString = "http://localhost:8081/PHP/Android_SQL.php";
    System.out.println("before try");

    String res = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(15000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //set input and output descript
        con.setDoInput(true);

        con.setDoOutput(false); // in needed?
        System.out.println("connecting");
        con.connect(); // won't work
        System.out.println("connect ");
        System.out.println(con.getURL());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            System.out.println(line);
        }


        json = sb.toString();
        br.close();
        return json;

    }catch (SocketTimeoutException a){
        a.getMessage();
    }catch (IOException b){
        b.getMessage();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("sueecssful");
    }
    return null;
}
```

I find one of the problem is SSL certification?

The logcat:

```
05-24 20:27:44.032 3089-3089/com.example.user.tophp I/System.out: click the button
05-24 20:27:44.033 3089-3237/com.example.user.tophp I/System.out: before try
05-24 20:27:44.033 1524-1595/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
05-24 20:27:44.033 3089-3237/com.example.user.tophp I/System.out: connecting
05-24 20:27:44.036 3089-3237/com.example.user.tophp I/System.out: sueecssful
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: after click the button , the logcat will only show the `tag` before `connect()` and after `finally{ }` , in other words , no error response

Comment: Can you copy/paste the relevant logcat, please?

Comment: @Marc i edit the answer to show the logcat

Comment: Check the following URL. That might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151359/java-httpurlconnection-doesnt-connect-when-i-call-connect

Comment: @Marc well, i got the article after i ask . However , I just follow the step by google "httpurlconnection to php" , and get no working as you look

Comment: Oh, read the answer below by ejohansson. I must be tired.

Comment: @Marc `IO Error java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8081) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)` thanks, after change the `catch exception` i get these message , i will try to solve it , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to `localhost:8081` which itself is the Android device.

Use `adb` to to port forward/reverse to your computer via the USB or you can simply replace `localhost` with the **IP of your computer on your local network**. Example: `192.168.0.2:8081`

- [adb forward remote port to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415797/adb-forward-remote-port-to-local-machine)
- https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#forwardports

Other potential issues:

```
catch (SocketTimeoutException a){
        a.getMessage();
    }catch (IOException b){
        b.getMessage();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

At least replace `a.getMessage();` with `a.printStackTrace()` to print the errors. But really you should use `Log.e("MyTag", "Error", a);` 
* https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

```
catch (SocketTimeoutException a){
        Log.e("MyTag", "Timout Error", a);
    }catch (IOException b){
        Log.e("MyTag", "IO Error", b);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyTag", "Error", e);
    }
```

Also make sure you have the following added to your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: thanks , i had add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` into manifest , and use url by my host name ( from no-ip). I'll change the `catch exception`statement.

Comment: thanks , i get the error message `IO Error java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8081) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)` I will try to solve it , thanks a lot

Comment: You cannot connect to `localhost`, because you are not running the webserver on your android device.