# REST POST method in Java

Tags: java, rest, post

I have this RESTful service down bellow:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response add(Student student) {
    if (service.add(student)) {
        return Response.status(200).entity(student).build();
    } else {
        return Response.status(500).entity("Error").build();
    }
}
```

and a use of that service:

```
public static void createStudent(String studentJsonString) {
    try {
        // priprema i otvaranje HTTP zahtjeva
        URL url = new URL(BASE_URL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); // 
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        // podaci za body dio zahtjeva
        JSONObject input = new JSONObject(studentJsonString);
        // slanje body dijela
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.toString().getBytes());
        os.flush();
        // @problem line
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this works.But, if I comment the line where I am getting the response code, the server side won't go into the add method, why ? The output stream is always flushed and closed, why do I need to read the response to 'activate' the service ?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of base class [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html):

> In general, creating a connection to a URL is a multistep process:
>
> - The connection object is created by invoking the `openConnection` method on a URL.
> - The setup parameters and general request properties are manipulated.
> - **The actual connection to the remote object is made, using the `connect` method.**
> - The remote object becomes available. The header fields and the contents of the remote object can be accessed.

The request isn't sent to the server until `connect` is called.

Any call to a method that requires the response will automatically call `connect` for you, as documented in the [`connect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect--) method:

> URLConnection objects go through two phases: first they are created, then they are connected. After being created, and before being connected, various options can be specified (e.g., `doInput` and `UseCaches`). After connecting, it is an error to try to set them. **Operations that depend on being connected, like `getContentLength`, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.**

Comment: But even if I add the line conn.connect(), after the flush, the service is't called.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151394/7729549 , the commit is only happening after calling these methods. That makes no sense, but, it is what it is.